# can wordpress do complex thing like react?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, content-management-system

very sorry if this sounds dumb because this is potentially a very dumb question

i've been learning front end web development for a couple of months now im learning react now and i loved it so much but there's one thing bugging me and it's CMS it seems really easy to use (i have a very little experience with it) and NOT as much fun, i just want to know if CMS matched my goals before learning it

so my goals are

- being able to make a fully functioning web app end to end such as
  [worldometer](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/)
- being able to make a living being a fullstack dev freelancer

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main flow in Wordpress is that it is based on a blog idea first rather than data management. But you can still make cool stuff, i'm working on a MCQ type website right now, with subscription which is pretty fun to make.
At the end of the day i'm pretty sure that if you want to dev a blog type website, wordpress is one of the best out there as it's natively made for it. But other than that you might want to consider something else.
Hope that my point of view will help.

Comment: Thank you I really needed this I've bee questioning my HTML, CSS, and react skills usefulness for my goals since  I've  heard about CMS. this really cleared things up for me . I'm still learning wordpress regardless tho is a nice way to hustle out quick buck and one of the most useful dev tools out there

Comment: For sure. And I mean, most of the time if you have your own business, clients want a showcase website, so Wordpress works great for this kind of work. But when we're talking about app like development,  React is probably more suiting.